# How to call a Smart Contract function using php

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, php

I am trying to call a simple function (no parameters) from a Smart Contract currently on the Rinkeby network using php. I have an ubuntu 22.04 server with Apache, I installed composer and the ethereum-php package (https://github.com/digitaldonkey/ethereum-php) but I can't seem to get it to work.

Is it possible to use composer dependencies for php files stored in /var/www/html or is that not possible? This might seem like a stupid question but I'm relatively new to this stuff and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks Joe B

If it is any help this is the code I am attempting to run:

```
<?php
  require '/home/ubuntu/php-ether/vendor/autoload.php';
  use Ethereum\Ethereum;

  $abi = [{"inputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"approved","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"bool","name":"approved","type":"bool"}],"name":"ApprovalForAll","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"previousOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferred","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"inputs":[],"name":"TOTAL_SUPPLY","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getApproved","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"}],"name":"isApprovedForAll","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"string","name":"uri","type":"string"}],"name":"mintTo","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ownerOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"renounceOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"safeTransferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"_data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"safeTransferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approved","type":"bool"}],"name":"setApprovalForAll","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"string","name":"uri","type":"string"}],"name":"setTokenURI","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes4","name":"interfaceId","type":"bytes4"}],"name":"supportsInterface","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"tokenURI","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"withdrawAll","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"withdrawAmount","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"}];

  $eth = new Ethereum('https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/9aa3d95b3bc440fa88ea12eaa4456161');
  $schemaContract = new SmartContract($abi, '<contract-address>', $eth);

  $result = $schemaContract->TOTAL_SUPPLY()->Val();
  echo $result;
  //Expected result = 10,000
?>
```

When I run this code using the ubuntu command line it results in a error saying:
Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "SmartContract" not found in /var/www/html/test.php:10
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in /var/www/html/test.php on line 10

Comment: " I can't seem to get it to work." Can you edit your question to include error messages and how do you test your code and what is the result you expect

Comment: ok sorry, I've done that now.

Comment: Perhaps you are missing the `use Ethereum\SmartContract;`, it is used in the examples directory.